# Powerpoint: Always format a specific string of text the same way

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In powerpoint (I'm using PP2016) is there an addon or something similar that will identify when specific string of text (within any textbox) and apply formatting rules based on that text?

Pseudio logic: IF textbox contains [some string] THEN apply some predefined formatting rule

***tl;dr***
My Purpose: I build presentations for teaching accounting and I like to highlight certain account names in different colors so people can easily follow along with how the accounts are changing. **For example,** across multiple slides I present how fixed factory overhead is treated differently between absorption and variable costing. It is tedious to select every instance where I type "Fixed Overhead" and apply red as the color.

Answer (score 0):

Run this on your presentation after editing to add your own terms and preferred colors.
It won't "see" text in tables or smartart or groups.

```
Sub HighlightText()

Dim colTermsAndColors As New Collection
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oRng As TextRange
Dim x As Long
Dim sName As String
Dim lColor As Long

' ADD YOUR TERMS AND COLORS HERE:
colTermsAndColors.Add ("BOB" & "|" & CStr(RGB(255, 0, 0)))
colTermsAndColors.Add ("CAROL" & "|" & CStr(RGB(255, 255, 0)))
colTermsAndColors.Add ("TED" & "|" & CStr(RGB(255, 0, 255)))
colTermsAndColors.Add ("ALICE" & "|" & CStr(RGB(0, 255, 0)))

For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSld.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
        If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
            For x = 1 To colTermsAndColors.Count
                sName = Split(colTermsAndColors(x), "|")(0)
                lColor = CLng(Split(colTermsAndColors(x), "|")(1))
                If InStr(UCase(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text), sName) > 0 Then
                    Set oRng = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(sName)
                    oRng.Font.Color.RGB = lColor
                End If
            Next
        End If
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```